# Why is address family mandatory when using icmp with pf?

Tags: networking, network-protocols, icmp, pf

there.

I wasn't able to find the answer for this question: when creating an ICMP pf rule, I must tell it's `inet` or `inet6` address family; I would like to know why, as `proto icmp` is for `inet` and `proto icmp6` is for `inet6`. Why does pf not deduce this by itself, as when using destination or source addresses?

Awaiting your answers,

Regards.

Comment: That weird thing to hear — `echo 'pass proto icmp' | sudo pfctl -nf -` works just fine here in MacOS thus meaning it's not mandatory at all.